# Sum of percent widths not rounded to 100%

Tags: html, css

I want to make a multi-segment progress bar.
It has to be horizontally centered, with a maximum width, but not a static one, so it can shrink if there is not enough space.

The problem is that sometimes the total progress is at 100%, but the segments could be at 33.33% and 66.66%.
The percentages are being calculated based on the width of the document, which may be an odd number, so the bar segments' widths are rounded in a way that leaves one pixel empty on the bar.

**HTML**

```
<div class="CENTER">
    <div class="BAR">
        <div class="SEGMENT ONE" style="width: 33.33%;"></div>
        <div class="SEGMENT TWO" style="width: 66.66%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.CENTER {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.BAR {
    height: 10px;
}

.SEGMENT {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.BAR { background-color: #F00; border: 1px solid #000; }

.SEGMENT.ONE { background-color: #FDA; }

.SEGMENT.TWO { background-color: #ADF; }
```

Play around with the width of the window after it's big enough for the bar to reach its maximum width.

There will be a red one pixel wide section on the right side of the bar.

## ***How can I avoid it?***

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CV6fp

Can you do it using that same HTML and without JavaScript, CSS?

Comment: If you specify more decimal digits (like `33.333333%`), on Firefox looks fine. However it isn't a good fix. It depends on what you exactly need, for example, to only remove the red color you can set the background of `.bar` the same color of `.two`, or you could use flex boxes, or even table boxes. What do you exactly need?

Comment: why not just make the bar's background #adf and only have one segment in it with a color of #fda? That would avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: It has to work on IE9+.
.BAR needs it own bg color to express the remaining progress when not at 100%, or an extra segment could do this, but anyway, .BAR can't know what the last non 0% segment is to take it's color.
I need to look up flex boxes.

Comment: @onetrickpony, even with those percents, which equal 100%, it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is not the it doesn't total 100%, it's 100% of what.
When the document has an odd number width .BAR gets rounded up, but .SEMENTS down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with table display?

http://jsfiddle.net/CV6fp/6/

```
.CENTER {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.BAR {
    height: 10px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.SEGMENT {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

.BAR { background-color: #F00; border: 1px solid #000; }

.SEGMENT.ONE { background-color: #FDA; }

.SEGMENT.TWO { background-color: #ADF; }
```

Comment: It looks great! Thanks.
I just gotta figure out why it didn't work on my actual code.

Comment: This is for sure the answer to what I asked.
It didn't work for me when I first tested on the actual code because I was using OVERFLOW: hidden to expand the bar to the remaining width left by the caption of the current percent, but I can update it to use width %100, which I didn't before.
Also, I have to set DISPLAY: none to any segments with 0% width, which the example doesn't have, but should. That also can be done with CSS, something like [style=width: 0%;]. So, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/CV6fp/3/

Basically, drop the width property off the div with class TWO.  Then make the same div NOT float left:

```
<div class="CENTER">
    <div class="BAR">
        <div class="SEGMENT ONE" style="width: 33.33%;"></div>
        <div class="SEGMENT TWO">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the style change:

```
.SEGMENT.TWO { background-color: #ADF; float:none; }
```

This means that second segment no longer floats:left, but I do think this may be what you are looking for.

**Update:**  And finally after much soul searching, a CSS only solution to solve all the issues mentioned on this page:

http://jsfiddle.net/CV6fp/7/

Two changes to CSS: (1) segments set to float:right, and (2) .SEGEMENT.ONE to override that and always float:left

```
.SEGMENT {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.SEGMENT.ONE { background-color: #FDA; float:left; }
```

Comment: I've been doing that programmatically. When the total is 100%, identify the last segment with non zero value and apply that style to it.
I figured with CSS3 there should be a way to do it with the HTML I provided.
Maybe with DISPLAY: table-cell, or something.

Comment: @CarlosGil - looks like Carlo Cannas figured out how to use table-cell -- looks good.

Comment: Whoa!, I just saw your update. I don't know why it works for the example provided. I appreciate it, but just so you know, there's a problem if the sum of all the segments is not 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/CarlitoGil/CV6fp/9/

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think that situation was part of the requirement.  Carlos Cannas solution is definitely less of a hack!  Glad you accepted it!

Answer (score -1):

In this case you may need to reduce accuracy to the tenth's place and use a `ceiling` rounding function on the final segment. This way you would get 33.3% and 66.7%.

Comment: If you change the percents in the example to 33.3% and 66.7%, which sum 100%, it still has the same problem.

Comment: It would? I assume since it equals 100% it wouldn't miss that pixel but I admit I haven't tried the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try: `.SEGMENT:last-child { float: none; width: auto !important; }`. This should make the last segment to fill the remaining space.

Comment: There may be more than two segments and the last child may has 0% width.

Comment: More than two segments is not a problem as I used :last-child selector. If the last segment has 0% width, I'd remove it from DOM completely and so this solution would still work.

Comment: Well, yeah. But I think there are better ways, I think, If your going to use JavaScript. It's my fault for not saying, but I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: +1 Don't see a problem with this. You could even make it :first-child(with some changes to the html) in order to support IE 8.0 I also don't understand how this got downvoted but another answer providing basically the same upvoted.